# "IncorrectTypeException" in my dashboard program

Tags: python, validation, plotly-dash

I'm having problems with my callback function and am  trying to debug my code. It's got multiple outputs that are supposed to show graphs.

```
@app.callback([ [Output(component_id='plot1', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot2', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot3', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot4', component_property='children'),
            Output(component_id='plot5', component_property='children')],
          [Input(component_id='input-type', component_property='value'),
            Input(component_id='input-year', component_property='value')],

           [State('plot1', 'children'), State('plot2', 'children'),
            State('plot3', 'children'), State('plot4', 'children'),
            State('plot5', 'children')]
          ])
```

I'm not entirely sure what's the problem, but I think it has something to do with my output parameters. At first I thought there was something wrong with the tuples, then I checked if it was an indention error. I even checked if it had something to do with the divisions that had 'plot4' & 'plot5'.
I spent the better part of 4 hours looking for references on what could be the cause of the error.
I think it has something to do with my output, *but I don't know what's the cause.*

I tried contacting the instructors but no help.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. [Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfqTO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an extra set of brackets in the callback statement. Live and learn.